# Generating Excel Spreadsheets - old format

Tags: javascript, excel, node.js

I figured out how to generate Excel spreadsheets that open with newer versions of Excel, but it turns out many clients are using old versions of Excel.  So I need to figure out how to generate old Excel files.

I used this to generate the files:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#XML_Spreadsheet

I don't need anything too complex, I just need to insert simple rows and columns.  I can't find anything that shows me the old format though (I'm hoping it's at least something human-readable).  I'm not even entirely sure which versions of Excel they are using.  Is there some way I can generate an Excel document that will work for older versions?

I'd prefer if there was something that let me generate the file myself, but a library would be fine too.  I'm using JS and Node, and all I can find is node-excel, which claims to have the first version done in March, and I assume will have the same problem as the simple program I wrote (not working with versions of Excel prior to 2002).

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Prior to 2002? Anything 2003 and prior uses the same format. How old do you have to go?!!

Comment: I'm no sure, above the example in wikipedia it says "The XML Spreadsheet format introduced in Excel 2002", so I figure they must be using versions older than that.  They're business type people, probably been using the same OS and programs since they started their businesses.
Any examples of what an older document would look like?

Comment: That's an XML spreadsheet, which is not compatible with any previous version of office. There is no older format available for XML spreadsheets.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/koles/ya-csv, CSV is supported by all versions of Excel

Comment: This may not work for you, but Perl's Spreadsheet::WriteExcel writes to older Excel formats -- you could take on porting this to Node.js (not a small task)  http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.38/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm

Comment: Buddy, if you need just simple data - save ordinary TXT file with default CSV separator (as per regional settings) with XLS extension - it will be opened in excel with data aligned to cells. Search through SO properly - I answered something similar about 3 weeks ago, but lost the link.

Comment: The older versions are binary files, the newer ones are XML. The best advice is to _ask them to send you an excel spreadsheet_.

Comment: PitaJ
I'm actually trying to avoid using CSV, some clients want CSV, others couldn't figure out how to import it
@Peter L
That might work, I had basically done this with the CSV, but clients couldn't import it (no idea why not), so I made Excel documents.  One thing is I had it set up for making different sheets, but only ended up using one sheet per document so far.
Creating actual Excel documents would be preferred, as it would be extendible (currently I only use simple data, there's no guarantee that in a month I won't be wanting more).